# Unexpected MySQL DATETIME behavior

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

I'm seeing what seems to me unexpected behavior from MySQL DATETIME when I'm trying to insert values into my table from my Java application. I've read a lot of StackOverflow questions and answers regarding DATETIME, but this seems to be a totally different issue.

My Java application uses MyBatis and [this DateTimeTypeHandler](https://github.com/LukeL99/joda-time-mybatis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/mybatis/handlers/DateTimeTypeHandler.java) to insert a joda DateTime value `2015-03-04T22:30:59.922Z`. (I also modified the above code to use the setTimestamp(int, Timestamp, Calendar) method but did not notice and difference in results).

What I see being inserted into the table is the value `2015-03-04 14:30:59.922`. I read that MySQL DATETIME uses the server default timezone. I live in the PDT timezone so I would expect the value to be `2015-03-04 15:30:59.922` (that's 15:30 instead of 14:30).

What's surprising is nothing in MySQL seems to indicate the PDT timezone.  So why would my datetime value in the table be 2015-03-04 14:30:59.922?

`mysql> select @@global.time_zone;
+--------------------+
| @@global.time_zone |
+--------------------+
| UTC                |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)`

`mysql> select @@session.time_zone;
+---------------------+
| @@session.time_zone |
+---------------------+
| UTC                 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)`

`mysql> SELECT @@system_time_zone;
+--------------------+
| @@system_time_zone |
+--------------------+
| UTC                |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)`

Answer (score 1):

March 4, 2015 was Standard time so the offset is -8 hours:

```
UTC (Time Zone)                   Wednesday, March 4, 2015 at 10:30:00 PM     UTC         
Los Angeles (U.S.A. - California) Wednesday, March 4, 2015 at 2:30:00 PM  PST UTC-8 hours
```

Today (May 28, 2015) is Daylight time so the offset is -7 hours:

```
UTC (Time Zone)                   Thursday, May 28, 2015 at 10:30:00 PM     UTC         
Los Angeles (U.S.A. - California) Thursday, May 28, 2015 at 3:30:00 PM  PDT UTC-7 hours
```

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks. However, I still don't get why it would use UTC-8 when the global and session and system timezones are set to UTC. How can I see what timezone DATETIME uses, and is there some way to override it?